# ESP32 pseudo hardware flow control for Bluetooth SPP

Tags: esp32, bluetooth

I'm using an ESP32 as a Bluetooth SPP to USB-serial null modem between a MacBook Pro (via SPP) and a laptop running Windows 11.

The ESP32 program logic is about as simple as it gets:

```
int nextByte;
void loop() {
    nextByte = Serial.read();
    if (nextByte > 0) {
        if (bt.isReady())
            bt.write(nextByte & 0xff);
        else
            dieAndBlinkLed();
    }
    nextByte = bt.read();
    if (nextByte > 0)
        Serial.write(nextByte & 0xff);
}
```

At the Mac & Windows ends, I'm using [JSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm) with event-driven reads and blocking direct writes.

The problem I'm having is, if I call `port.writeBytes(byteArray, byteArray.length)` with a byteArray that's longer than approximately 520-540 bytes (i.e. slightly longer than 512, but way less than 768 or 1024, let alone 4096), it seems to silently drop bytes.

I have JSerialComm's receive listener configured to buffer bytes and deliver them to my callback when a 0 byte is received (I'm using COBS to escape-out zero bytes). It *seems* to be dropping the heads and delivering only the 520-540 byte tails of each frame, but I'm not really sure what's happening between the moment I call port.writeBytes() on the Mac end and send a chunk larger than ~540 bytes to the Bluetooth SPP port and the moment the callback at the other end delivers only the tail end.

If push came to shove, I suppose I could rewrite the program to use 500-byte frames (~509-512 bytes with overhead) instead of 4000-byte frames (~4010-4028 bytes with overhead), but then the relative overhead would quadruple from ~0.6% to ~2.5% (every frame has a 4-byte header at the start, a 4-byte crc32 at the end, and 1-16 bytes of COBS overhead... 1, plus one for every 254+ bytes in a row without at least one zero byte).

Before I throw in the towel, I'm trying to get a better understanding of what the **actual** hard constraints imposed by esp32 Bluetooth SPP *are*, and make sure I'm not just making a stupid mistake somewhere along the line that's causing behind the scenes flow control to fail in a way I can fix.

Off the top of my head, I can think of the following points of failure:

- JSerialComm's handling of the bytes before delivering them to OSX
- OSX's serial buffer overflowing because the bluetooth spp stack is declining to accept bytes while it's busy (re)transmitting earlier ones
- my esp32 event loop being too slow and dropping bytes
- serial wire loss between the esp32 and cp2102
- overflowing the cp2102's buffer in between USB polls
- USB control mode being unable to ferry the bytes from the cp2102 through the USB port fast enough (64 bytes/millisecond max... assuming it actually gets *called* every millisecond, and most of those 64 bytes are available for use)
- the cp2102 driver on Windows overflowing its own buffer before JSerialComm grabs its contents
- JSerialComm itself having a buffer smaller than ~576 bytes and overflowing before it sees the next 0 and delivers the chunk to my callback

Before tackling the possibility of a JSerialComm-related problem at StackOverflow, I want to eliminate anything esp32-related as a potential problem.

So.. first... **is there any possibility that the way I'm relaying data between the ports a byte at a time could be the problem?** For what it's worth, dieAndBlinkLed() has never triggered... and the problems I've observed so far have involved data entering the pipeline at the Mac/bluetooth-SPP end and ending up at the USB/Windows end.

Does anybody have any idea what the max sustainable SPP bitrate between a Macbook Pro (M3, 2023 edition) and esp32 a few inches away even IS?

As I understand it, SPP uses timeslices and a "raw" link rate somewhere in the neighborhood of 1-2mbps. However, I've also gotten the impression that you're only "guaranteed" (in the loosest sense) 1 slice per period, and that you normally can only use more than one if a whole complicated chain of dependencies and conditions is satisfied... including "both bluetooth modules are from the same vendor", "same bluetooth stack at both ends", and "bluetooth stack itself is willing to use more".

AFAIK, Espressif and Apple almost beyond doubt don't satisfy the "both bluetooth modules from same vendor" requirement, and "same bluetooth stack" would probably be the final deathblow even if they did (because *everything* Apple does is proprietary).

(**UPDATE:** It looks like the effective best-case transfer rate for normal SPP is 128kbps... anything faster is a vendor-proprietary extension that probably won't work in this situation).

**Is there anything I can/must do at the esp32 end** to eliminate  *it* as a likely chokepoint? Like, is the size of the esp32's local bluetooth and/or Serial port buffer something that's configurable via esptool.py? Or, as theorized earlier, is the esp32 *itself* (and the software running on it) likely to be the *least* of my problems?

Any additional insight anyone might have about SPP (via JSerialComm or otherwise) between an ESP32 and "real" computer is welcome, though I suspect that's probably something I'll have to ask at StackOverflow.

---

### Update

I ran some experiments at three different baudrates, and transmitted 501 510-512 byte packets with varying delays between them.

Surprising discovery: reducing the baudrate made things **worse**

- with 200ms delay between packets, I received 499, 499, and 500 packets at 57600, 115200, and 230400 baud respectively.
- with 100ms delay between packets, I received 404, 474, and 486 packets at 57600, 115200, and 230400 baud
- with 50ms delay between packets, I received 47(!!!), 335, and 423 packets at 57600, 115200, and 230400 baud
- with 25ms delay between packets, I received 14(!!!), 75, and 311 packets at 57600, 115200, and 230400 baud

Revised theory about what I think might be going wrong: I think the bluetooth stack is buffering the outbound bytes and lying to the serial port driver that they've been sent, and reducing the baudrate makes things worse by creating a logjam further downstream.

- At 57600 baud, a block of data hits the ESP32 at some much higher signaling rate via bluetooth, then logjams in the esp32 because it's trying to shove all 500 bytes through a metaphorical cocktail straw into the cp2102.
- At 230400 baud, a block of data takes longer to transmit between the Macbook and ESP32 than the baudrate would suggest, but the combination of throttling the rate it's being fed to the Macbook's bluetooth stack and using a fast baudrate between the ESP32 and CP2102 allows the incoming buffer on the esp32 to be emptied almost immediately upon receipt.

Assuming I'm right, I think I somehow need to find a way to get the serial port library to recognize when the bluetooth stack's outbound buffer is full. I don't know whether the problem is with my code, with the serial port library (JSerialComm), or can't be solved at all within the constraints of Java's ability to communicate with Apple's bluetooth stack.

Comment: The `read()` is blocking call and it might be waiting for example whole second until it times out. Meanwhile other serial might have steady flow of bytes that nobody consumes for long time

Comment: Where do you see that read() is a blocking call? I was under the impression that it immediately returns a value between 0..255 if there's at least one byte in the buffer, and -1 if the buffer is empty (source: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/)

Comment: You are right, I had it somehow "stored" in memory as blocking, but it was for readString and similar https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/

Comment: If it's any consolation, I almost wish you *had* been right, because at least *then* I'd have an explanation of where the problem is occurring. 

My current (as yet unverified) theory is that maybe JSerialComm's writeBytes() blocks until the bluetooth stack merely *accepts* the bytes for sending, as opposed to blocking until they're confirmed to have been sent. So, JSerialComm and I might be relentlessly throwing huge byte arrays at it expecting the buffer to already be empty, and eventually overflowing the bt stack's own buffer without any warning.

Comment: Maybe try to measure how long it stays on different parts of loop (probably just set some pins before and clear after it and watch it on oscilloscope)